# Breaking my JS into smaller bits

Tags: javascript, jquery

My JavaScript file is now more than 1000 lines long. I need to make it more manageable. Here is the basic structure of my file:

```
// Some settings (easily put in a separate file)

// Some jQuery plugins (easily put in a separate file)

$(function () {
   var gadget1 = (function() {
       var private, public;
       // stuff
       return public;
   }());

   var gadget2 = (function() { // gadget2 uses gadget1
       var private, public;
       // stuff
       return public;
   }());

   var gadget3 = (function() {  // gadget3 uses gadget1 and gadget2
       var private, public;
       // stuff
       return public;
   }());

   // Playing around with the gadgets.
});
```

The bulk of my code is wrapped in `$(document).ready()` and is made of "gadgets" that are chunky closures. How can I separate each "gadget" in a separate module?

Comment: your gadget3 is named gadget2

Comment: While it may be more manageable in separate files, your code will load faster in the browser if you keep it in one file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the namespacing pattern

```
MyAPP = {}
MyAPP.Gadget1 = (function () {
    //blah blah
})()
```

and then have a helper

```
MyAPP.helpers = (function () {
  //here are my helper functions/properties etc.
})()
```

These namespaced objects would be in separate files.

Comment: Yup. And breaking them out like this doesn't preclude using them in document ready. In your document ready you just have MyAPP.Gadget1() as a function call.

Comment: The problem I'm getting with this is that `MyApp.Gadget1` and `MyApp.helpers` both depend on a common set of variables. That means that I need to make those variables namespaced also.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to handle the creation of each gadget in a separate file, one file for each gadget.  Just be sure to include the files in the correct order, and make the gadgets global (by defining them on `window`).

A better solution would be create function definitions (define a 'class' as it were) for each gadget.  The constructor of the gadget would take its dependencies.  If you define each gadget type in its own file, then you can just create them in the `ready()` call.  This approach has the advantage that should want to create more gadgets of any type, you can do so, because you defined them as their own functions.

Comment: No need to make them all global, just need one global variable.

Comment: Then define a namespace and put them in there.  The point is, break up your gadget definitions into separate files.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to get yourself familiar with [make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/)

Have each of the files separate and make a build script that joins them all together.